# Audio/Voice Recording Device

Tags: sensors, audio, raspberrypi

I'd like to build a little voice recorder for my grandmother. She told me "I get a lot of idea when I'm driving but then I forget them. I want a necklace where I can just press a button and it'll record my voice and I can press a button and it'll stop recording." She wants each recording to save as a separate file. I was thinking of concealing a mini Arduino board or Rasberry Pi or something in a necklace, with a removable micro sd card. Or something like that. I just don't know where to start, I don't have much experience with this. Does anyone have any tips on what kind of device I could use or where to start? I suggested that she just have Siri take notes for her on her iPhone but she wants something around her neck, and she wants me to make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this amazing breakout board. Its all you need. [SparkFun Voice Recorder Breakout - ISD1932](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10653)

Moreover, If you thinking on letting that device talk back, try this: [VoiceShield](http://www.spikenzielabs.com/SpikenzieLabs/VoiceShield.html)

Well, there is also an instructable for this, [HERE](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Mega-Audio-File-logging/). This Instructable will show you how audio input can be repeatedly added to a 512 byte buffer and then transferred to a SD card in real time. The audio file can be played back on a standard audio application or analysed byte by byte.

Comment: Thank you for the start! The SparkFun breakout board seems to have been discontinued, do you know of any similar ones? The closest thing I could find was the ICStation ICSH041A, and I really couldn't find much of a description of it.

Comment: [This](http://www.dx.com/p/diy-isd1820-onboard-microphone-voice-recording-playing-module-for-arduino-148821#.VwCPQqR97IV) one is easily available and easy to use. And One that is mentioned [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-voice-control/) is amazing but might be little expensive.